# Custom json return in SpringController

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, controller

How to use different json serialization in different springboot controller methods?
Lets say I have

```
class Guy{
private String name;
private int age;
private List<String> hobbies;
}
```

In some controller methods, I just want to return the name of a Guy as a json.
In some methods I want to return name and age as json.
And in some methods I just want to return the list as json.
Annotating the properties in the POJO doesn't make sense, because each method has different return specifications...

First try is to use @JsonView annotation

```
class Guy{
   @JsonView(Views.MyTestView.class)
   private String name;
   @JsonView(Views.MyTestView.class)
   private int age;
   private List<String> hobbies;
}
```

My view is the following:

```
public class Views {
    public class MyTestView{}
}
```

and in the controller I used:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
  return mapper.writerWithView(Views.MyTestView.class)
               .writeValueAsString(guy);
```

Edit: Its now working like this

Comment: You can use Spring support for Jackson's Json Views or (assuming you are using Spring Data JPA) Spring Data projections as referred to in answer to the above.

Comment: I tried the json view described here (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) but this is somehow ignored and it still serializes all properties

Comment: You are obviously using it incorrectly then.

Comment: It's working now: I forgot to disable the default_view_inclusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson Mixins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) and have a mixin for each condition specifying which attributes to be ignored/added to json.

Answer (score 0):

Use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), here you can simply define interfaces based on your needs.

For working examples visit [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).